# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Error encountered while using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, websphere, slf4j

Here are the versions that I am using

hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar
WAS 8.5.5.22
jdk1.8
slf4j-api-1.5.10.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.5.10.jar

I am seeing the following errors:

Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org/slf4j/spi/LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
at org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLocationAwareLogger.doLog(Slf4jLocationAwareLogger.java:91)
at org.jboss.logging.Slf4jLocationAwareLogger.doLogf(Slf4jLocationAwareLogger.java:82)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.debugf(Logger.java:564)
at org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders.find(LoggerProviders.java:33)
at org.jboss.logging.LoggerProviders.(LoggerProviders.java:28)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:2163)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger$1.run(Logger.java:2263)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:691)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2227)
at org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Logger.java:2214)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.(Configuration.java:194)

Any idea why I am seeing this error